# Storing XML Tag content to different variable using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm currently having a issue in my Project that involes an XML stored in a String variable. I'm trying to save the content of the XML in different variables.

Using the common JAXB method that involes the same variable name and the tag name should solve my problem. In this case, I have to store in different variable names.

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PORTAL>
    <NAME>PERSON 2.0</NAME>
    <ID>99995</ID>
    <DATAGENERATIO>2008-04-10</DATAGENERATIO>
    <HOURGENERATIO>05:07:35</HOURGENERATIO>
    <LANGUAGE>EN</LANGUAGE>
    <XMLVERSIO>1.0</XMLVERSIO>
</PORTAL>
```

And this is the class used to store the content of that XML.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="PORTAL")
public class ApiPubPortal {

    private long idPortal;
    private String idIdioma;
    private String nombre;
    private Date dataGeneracio;
    private String versionXml;
}
```

I already try using `@XmlElement(name="ID")` but it gives me `IllegalAnnotationExceptions`

If anybody can help me with this I'll be thankfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have getter and setters for all your private fields. An example given below:

```
private long idPortal;

@XmlElement(name = "ID")
public long getIdPortal()
{
 return idPortal;
}
public void setIdPortal(long idPortal)
{
 this.idPortal = idPortal;
}
```

**Please note to put @XmlElement(name = "ID") on your getter.**

Comment: This is it, I was putting the @XmlElement(name="ID") in the variable all this time, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

With SimpleXml you can use the @XmlName annotation to tell the parser what the XML tag name is that is linked to a field. There is no need for getters and setters in your POJO. This will work:

```
@XmlName("PORTAL")
public class ApiPubPortal {
    @XmlName("ID")
    private long idPortal;
    private String idIdioma; // Its not clear to which XML tag this maps
    @XmlName("NAME")
    private String nombre;
    @XmlName("DATAGENERATIO")
    private String dataGeneracio;
    @XmlName("XMLVERSIO")
    private String versionXml;
}
```

Your XML can then be serialized this way:

```
final String xml = ...
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final ApiPubPortal portal = simple.fromXml(xml, ApiPubPortal.class);
```

The library is in maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```